# How to precisely define the natural domain of a function?

Tags: functions

It is commonly defined as every real number that let the expression make sense. Is there a more precise and rigorous way to define it?

Actually I have some idea about this:

First, define basic functions like +,-,*($\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$),/($\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$)

Then, define arithmetic on functions. For example: $h=f+g$, where the domain of $h$ is the intersection of the domain of $f$ and $g$, and for every $x$ in the domain of $h$, $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

And then we can talk about the natural domain of functions that are combinations of those operations.

Comment: What is the scope of functions whose natural domain you want to define?

Comment: elementary functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but too long for a comment.

We have operations that you mention ($+,*,-,/$), and you've proposed a way to apply these to functions (pointwise) and a way to define the natural domain of a combination (say $f+g$) in terms of the domains of $f,g$. I like this approach, but I would make the following observations.

1. You have a method of combining functions (say $f,g\mapsto f+g$), but we don't yet have any functions to combine. Constant functions and the identity function $f(x)=x$ would be a good start, but probably not everything you want to build up all elementary functions (including exponentials, for example).
2. A general procedure could be: Start with a set $\mathcal{C}$ of functions with specified natural domains. For example, $\mathcal{C}$ could be the functions $+,*,-,/$ that you defined, where each has natural domain $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ except division, because we can't divide by zero. However, $\mathcal{C}$ could contain some functions whose domains are $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, as opposed to Cartesian products. For example, I would start with addition, multiplication, scaling, and inversion. Scaling would be the family of functions $x\mapsto cx$ (one function for each $c\in\mathbb{R}$). Addition and scaling together give you subtraction, because $f-g=f+(-1*g)$. Multiplication and inversion ($x\mapsto 1/x$) give you division. Then we could explicitly define the natural domain of $f+g$ in terms of the natural domains of $f,g$ and $+$, exactly as you describe. More generally, if $F\in\mathcal{C}$ is a function whose natural domain $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, and if we have $f,g$ with (already defined) natural domains $\text{dom}_f$, $\text{dom}_g$, we could define the natural domain of $f+g$ to be $$\{x\in \text{dom}_f\times \text{dom}_g:(f(x),g(x))\in D\}.$$ This is exactly what you've described thus far. Your examples of $F(f,g)$ have been $f+g$, $f-g$, $f*g$, $f/g$, and the natural domains have always been $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}\times (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$.  However, I would remark that we almost certainly want composition of functions to be an allowed operation, and the rule would be more complicated. The natural domain of $f\circ g$ would be $\{x\in \text{dom}_g:g(x)\in \text{dom}_f\}$.
3. We need a way to formally say what is the collection of functions to which we extend the definition of "natural domain". You say "elementary functions", but what does that include? Wikipedia gives a definition, but if the goal is formality, we want a different approach. We could very generally say: If we start with a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of functions and a collection $\mathcal{C}$ of ways to build new functions from old, we can take $\overline{\mathcal{F}}^\mathcal{C}$ to be the smallest collection of functions which contains all of the members of $\mathcal{F}$ and such that if $f,g\in \overline{\mathcal{F}}^\mathcal{C}$ and $F\in\mathcal{C}$, then $F(f,g)\in \overline{\mathcal{F}}^\mathcal{C}$. This is a formal definition (if somewhat abstract). The level of abstraction here might make it more challenging to say that we can unambiguously define "natural domain" for all functions in $\overline{\mathcal{F}}^\mathcal{C}$, given that we have "natural domain" defined on $\mathcal{F}$.
4. We start with a formal definition of "basic" functions. Constant functions and the identity function $x\mapsto x$ need to be there. Exponentials/logarithms/trig functions could arguably be in there.
5. We would run into an issue of "natural domain": What's the natural domain of $x/x$? It has a removable singularity at $x=0$. Do you want $0$ in the domain or not? If not, the approach works. But if you want the definition of "natural domain" to remove the removable singularities, this is not dealt with by the rules of combining the domains of the numerator and denominator.
6. There is another issue to be aware of: If we have natural domain of $f,g,h$ defined, then we have $f+g+h=(f+g)+h=f+(g+h)$. Then we have the potential to have multiple, conflicting definitions of "natural domain": One which comes from realizing $f+g+h$ as the sum of $f+g$ with $h$, and another which comes from realizing $f+g+h$ as the sum o $f$ with $g+h$. This isn't a defeater, but it should be addressed in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

> define arithmetic on [natural domains of] functions

To begin with, you'd have to define what the natural domain (aka the domain of definition) is of *elementary functions*, e.g. exp or log.

You'd also have to define what results from the *composition of functions* -- which I think is the really tricky part, since it requires also knowing the *range* (image) of any given function, which is not even always computable...

Finally, you'd have to define, for every possible/given *arithmetic operator*, e.g. div or pow, how, given the natural domain of the arguments, it determines a natural domain for the combined expression -- which (if I am not missing anything) amounts to taking the **intersection** of the argument's natural domains, plus possible additional constraints specific to the operator, e.g. that the divisor in a division cannot be zero, which themselves can be expressed in terms of sets to be intersected together with the arguments' natural domains.

Then, the *non-elementary functions* would be (non-elementary) function expressions containing, as atomic terms, elementary functions as well as any other functions that are simply given together with their domain of definition, and built up by use of function composition and arithmetic operators.

That said, more precisely in a formal treatment there would be not so much a distinction between "functions" and "operators" (everything is a function), but a distinction between "functions" and "expressions". But I think the informal (and admittedly basic) description I have provided above is a better first approximation as to how to understand and approach the problem.